# How to intersect two audio channels?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Not mix or merge, I need to intersect channels, like: L - R

I can do this with createScriptProcessor:

```
let processor = context.createScriptProcessor(512, 2, 1)
processor.onaudioprocess = e => {
  let inputL = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
      inputR = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1),
      output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
      len = inputL.length,
      i = 0;
  for (; i < len; i++) {
    output[i] = inputL[i] - inputR[i];
  }
}
```

This do what I want, but ... is there a way to do this without **createScriptProcessor**, for example with createChannelMerger / createChannelSplitter? I'm looking for a more effective way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found a solution!**

This is

```
inputLeft - inputRight
```

the same as

```
inputLeft + inputRightInvert
```

where *inputRightInvert* is the invertion of right channel.

- To split channels we can use *createChannelSplitter*.
- To invert channel we can use *createGain* with *value* -1

The result:

```
splitter = context.createChannelSplitter(2) 
merger   = context.createChannelMerger(1)

invertRightChannel = context.createGain() 
invertRightChannel.gain.value = -1

input.connect(splitter)

// left channel  
splitter.connect(merger, 0, 0) 
// right invert channel 
splitter.connect(invertRightChannel, 1) 
invertRightChannel.connect(merger, 0, 0)

merger.connect(output)
```

**What superiority?**

- It works faster (~3x)
- No bugs (solution with createScriptProcessor make some artefacts)
- Better Sync (createScriptProcessor make some latency)